# how to remove slider in the irex lite theme

Tags: slider, clickable

I have some problems with the size on the sliders... the recommended 800x500 doesn't seem to be correct, as the bottom of every photo disappears in google chrome on my computer.... I have also tried with lower values, but it doesn't look the same in all browsers!

And the most important: I really need to have the sliders clickable... (link to different pages)

Can you please help me with these 2 things?

If this is difficult...
I prefer to remove the integrated irex slider and insert the metaslider where I can add links to each slider photo...

metaslider id=1407

But I don't know how to turn off your slider... and replace it with the metaslider...

Can you please help me? thank you so much:)

My site is www.ytago.com